# why does movsw instruction increments the si and di registers by2 while movsb instruction increments the si and di registers by 1?

Tags: assembly, fasm

I was working with the movsb and movsw instruction in assembly language using the flat assembler. Now, i noticed that when the movsb instruction is executed the SI and DI register is incremented by 1 while the movsw instruction increments the SI AND DI register by 2. I am a bit confused why? Can anyone explain me the reason. I am adding my codes below for both the instruction with comments. Please help me out. Thanks!

Using the movsb instruction(Flat assembler)

```
cld ;clear direction flag

lea si,[val]  ;the memory address of source is loaded in the source register

lea di,[v];the memory address of the destination is loaded in the destination register

mov cx,5 ; the counter basically executes for the number of characters in the array

rep movsb ; repeats the instruction for 5 times

val:
     db 'A' 
     db 'B'
     db 'C'
     db 'D'
     db 'E'

v db 5 DUP(?)
```

Using the movsw instruction(Flat assembler)

```
cld    ;clear the direction flag

lea si,[a];load the address of a in source
;register
lea di,[b] ;load the address of b in destination
;register
mov cx,3
rep movsw  ;copy each word from source to
;destination and increment the source register
;by 2 and destination register by 2

a: 
  dw '1'
  dw '2'
  dw '3'

b dw 3 DUP(?)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`movsw`, `movsb`, `movsd`, `movsq` are instructions used to copy data from the source location `DS:(ER)SI` to destination location `ES:(ER)DI`.

They are useful because there is no *mem-to-mem* move instruction in IA32e.

They are meant to be used in cycles (for example by using the `rep` prefix), so besides moving the data they also increments (if *DF* flag, Direction Flag, is 0) or decrements (if *DF* flag is 1) the pointers to the source and destination locations, i.e. the `(ER)SI` and `(ER)DI` registers.

From the assembly programmer perspective the memory is byte-addressable, it means that each address store one byte.

- `movsb` moves a byte, so the register are incremented/decremented by 1.
- `movsw` moves a WORD (2 bytes), so the register are incremented/decremented by 2.
- `movsd` moves a DWORD (Double Word, 2 Word, 4 bytes), so the register are incremented/decremented by 4.
- `movsq` moves a QWORD (Quad Word, 4 words, 8 bytes), so the register are incremented/decremented by 8.

Answer (score 2):

Because `movsb` moves (or copies, really) one Byte, while `movsw` moves one Word. A word in x86 terminology is 2 bytes.

From Intel's manual:

> After the move operation, the (E)SI and (E)DI registers are incremented or decremented automatically according
>   to the setting of the DF flag in the EFLAGS register.
>  The registers are incremented or
>   decremented by 1 for byte operations, by 2 for word operations, or by 4 for doubleword operations.

Or, more formally:

```
IF (Byte move)
  THEN IF DF = 0
    (E)SI ← (E)SI + 1;
    (E)DI ← (E)DI + 1;
  ELSE
    (E)SI ← (E)SI – 1;
    (E)DI ← (E)DI – 1;
  FI;
ELSE IF (Word move)
  THEN IF DF = 0
    (E)SI ← (E)SI + 2;
    (E)DI ← (E)DI + 2;
  FI;
  ELSE
    (E)SI ← (E)SI – 2;
    (E)DI ← (E)DI – 2;
  FI;
```

Answer (score 0):

`movsb` moves a byte from `SI` to `DI` and decrements/increments them both by one byte. `movsw` moves a word from `SI` to `DI` and decrements/increments them both by two bytes (a word). Each of these instructions basically do the same thing, except they move different *sizes* of memory.

I hope this helps!